# Laravel 5.4 can't run "php artisan preset react" comand

Tags: reactjs, laravel, laravel-5, preset

Laravel 5.4 can't run `php artisan preset react` comand
Getting "Command "preset" is not defined." responde.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

For Laravel 7+ projects:

```
composer require laravel/ui
php artisan ui react
```

https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/frontend#introduction

For Laravel 5.5+ projects:

```
php artisan preset react
```

https://medium.com/@taylorotwell/laravel-frontend-presets-eca312958def

Comment: I'm getting this error on Laravel 7.0.3. Did they remove it?

Comment: @musicin3d - nope, but it seems they changed the API: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/frontend

Answer (score 8):

Steps to run React in 7.x and 8.x in laravel

```
composer require laravel/ui
php artisan ui react
npm install
npm run dev
```

To check if for react working on laravel project you can add React Developer Chrome extension and hover on to the icon. It will show that application is using react.
Then do

```
php artisan serve
```

and add below lines in your head of welcome.blade.php

```
<link href="/css/app.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Add Below line in your body tag

```
<div id="example"></div>
```

Add below line after closing body tag

```
<script src="/js/app.js"></script>
```

and remove the defined complete style
Refresh your laravel page and hen you will hover on the extension for react which is added in chrome it will show that the page is using React JS. Successfully the ReactDOM is loaded.
Hope this helps to run a basic laravel + react welcome page

Comment: This worked for me but i had to add --ignore-platform-reqs to the composer command to get past dependency errors

Answer (score 4):

In Laravel 7.x, the scaffolding API has changed:

```
php artisan ui react
```

https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/frontend

Answer (score 2):

Laravel 5.5 a new Artisan preset command allows you to replace default tools with other tools like React, Bootstrap, and even removing all of it.

1. The React preset command can be initialized through Artisan:

   *php artisan preset react*
2. The Bootstrap preset is useful if you prefer not to use any
   JavaScript scaffolding at all, but still, want to keep the Bootstrap
   CSS.

   *php artisan preset bootstrap*
3. The final preset option is “none” which will remove both Bootstrap
   and Vue.js:

   *php artisan preset none*