# Error while running php artisan preset react

Tags: php, reactjs

Why i'm getting error while running `php artisan preset react` in my console. I'm working in my online enrollment system and i wanna use laravel and react. But i got stuck in this problem and i dont know about this error.

[image: this is what appears in my console]

Comment: This may be useful; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48381322/laravel-5-4-cant-run-php-artisan-preset-react-comand?rq=1

Comment: Your image of text [isn't very helpful](//meta.unix.stackexchange.com/q/4086).  It can't be read aloud or copied into an editor, and it doesn't index very well, meaning that other users with the same problem are less likely to find the answer here.  Please [edit] your post to incorporate the relevant text directly (preferably using copy+paste to avoid transcription errors).